# Sum of Weierstrass points on a curve of genus three

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let C be a smooth complex projective curve of genus 2 and X a non trivial Galois
cover of degree 2 of C. So X has genus three and it is hyperelliptic, hence X has 8
Weierstrass points. Can one compute the sum of these eight Weierstrass points in Pic(X)?

Comment: For any hyperelliptic curve $X$ of genus $g$, the sum of the Weierstrass points is equal to $(g+1)g^{1}_{2}$ in $\operatorname{Pic}(X) $.

Comment: Thank you abx. Do you have a reference?

Comment: If you write the curve as $y^2 = f(x)$ with $f$ a polynomial of degree $2g+2$, then $y$ is a rational function that vanishes to order $1$ at each Weierstrass point and has a pole of order $g+1$ at each point at $\infty$, i.e. the two points of a divisor equivalent to the $g^1_2$ class. This rational function gives a linear equivalence.